# If i get Special Characters from Server to Javascript file converting as � character in success response

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, encoding

I am using java as my backend Language and sql server as my db and jquery and javascript for front-end  coding and i am calling an ajax call to get the data and in network i am getting the data correctly but in success response the special characters are converting to � and below is my piece of code.

$.ajax({

```
    url: 'getLevelValue.html',
                 type: 'POST',
                 async : false,
                 data: {

                       clientName : (clientName),
                       level2Id : (level2Id),
                       level3Value : (level3Value),
                 },

                 dataType: "text",

                 contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",

                 success: function (result){
```

//in result i am getting � character but the actual characters are á, é, í, ó, ú 
} 
});

Comment: Either your database is not configured to use UTF-8, or the JS file itself is not encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: using `async:false` is highly discouraged

Comment: yeah i know it's just a hand written code and from database it's coming correct result but in javascript  it's converting and i made javascript file  encoded as UTF-8 in html file using charset=utf-8.

Comment: Files are not encoded with a meta tag, they are encoded when saving them.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> this code i already put in my html file

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. Charset only tells browser to get ready for UTF-8 encoded content, but if the content is not saved as UTF-8 encoded, browser can't read and output it properly.

Comment: okay thanks i will check :)

Comment: I checked in my code base and it is in utf-8 format only and i followed all the instruction from this link https://stijndewitt.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/ and everything same as given in the link but still no luck :(

Comment: Check the database too, and the write/read queries of this specific record, you can temporarily change the encoding for a query.